# Не могу пересчитать веса для нейронной сети после обучения!

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Очень надеюсь на помощь. Только начал смотреть что-то по нейросетям для учебного проекта. Учёба программирование затрагивает очень по касательной, но вот потребовалось что-то сделать своими руками. Хотел, чтобы нейросеть пересчитала значения для весов после обучения, но вместо 7 пересчитанных значений получаю вот это:

```
Random starting synaptic weights:
[[-0.16595599]
 [ 0.44064899]
 [-0.99977125]
 [-0.39533485]
 [-0.70648822]
 [-0.81532281]
 [-0.62747958]]
New synaptic weights after training:
[[ 7.73470947  1.21188474 -4.90030707  2.1117925  -1.56089714 -0.89013968
  -2.35685783]
 [-1.29747478  5.83175121  0.32427316 -6.68767742 -3.61238143 -4.13911369
  -3.10813867]
 [-3.28058454  4.122018    9.38853135  2.11171936 -0.7326107  -0.60927343
  -2.40796406]
 [ 6.96264109  0.7131929   5.3749925  12.12223064  2.52991497  3.85074195
  -0.44564184]
 [-0.40741729 -0.09576421 -0.10071769 -0.32434514 13.0174758   2.69218577
  -1.27188238]
 [-4.65664836 -4.88666432 -4.67500763 -4.50632495 -4.22781114  7.22895077
  -4.97396353]
 [-0.62747958 -0.62747958 -0.62747958 -0.62747958 -0.62747958 -0.62747958
  -0.62747958]]
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что раз получается такой массив, значит проблема в том, что где-то происходит умножение уже имеющегося массива весов на что-то?
Сам код вот такой:

```
class NeuralNetwork():
    """Класс для нейронной сети"""

    def __init__(self):
        random.seed(1)
        

        self.synaptic_weights = 2 * random.random((7, 1)) - 1

    def __sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + exp(-x))

    def __sigmoid_derivative(self, x):
        return x * (1 - x)

    def train(self, training_set_inputs, raining_set_outputs, number_of_training_iterations):
        for iteration in range(number_of_training_iterations):
            output = self.think(training_set_inputs)

            error = training_set_inputs - output

            adjustment = dot(training_set_inputs.T, error * self.__sigmoid_derivative(output))

            self.synaptic_weights = self.synaptic_weights + adjustment

    def think(self, inputs):
        return self.__sigmoid(dot(inputs, self.synaptic_weights))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    neural_network = NeuralNetwork()

    print("Random starting synaptic weights: ")
    print(neural_network.synaptic_weights)

    training_set_inputs = array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                                 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                 [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                                 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

    training_set_outputs = array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]).T

    neural_network.train(training_set_inputs, training_set_outputs, 10000)

    print("New synaptic weights after training: ")
    print(neural_network.synaptic_weights)
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда копируете код https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/10/simple-neural-network-python.html, будьте внимательны при переименовании переменных:

`error = training_set_inputs - output` -> `error = training_outputs - output` в оригинале или `error = raining_set_outputs - output` в вашем коде.

Если что, этот код не пересчитывает веса ПОСЛЕ обучения, а пересчитывает их во время него.

Answer (score 0):

Вот исправил:)

```
#-*-coding:utf8-*-
from numpy import random
import numpy as np
class NeuralNetwork():
    """Класс для нейронной сети"""

    def __init__(self):
        random.seed(42)
        self.l_r=0.07
        

        self.synaptic_weights = 2 * random.random((1, 7)) - 1 # делаю нейрон в 'своем' стиле

    def __sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

    def __sigmoid_derivative(self, x):
        return self.__sigmoid(x) * (1 - self.__sigmoid(x))

    def train(self, training_set_inputs, training_set_outputs, number_of_training_iterations):
        for iteration in range(number_of_training_iterations):
            for retrive_ind in range(len(training_set_inputs)):
              weighted ,output = self.think(np.array([training_set_inputs[retrive_ind]])) # передаем только один вектор причем для numpy нужен 2d массив
              #print("output",output) # 1 число
              

              error = (training_set_outputs[retrive_ind] - output) * self.__sigmoid_derivative(weighted)
              print("error",error)

              adjustment_delta = np.dot(error, self.synaptic_weights )
              
              X=np.array([training_set_inputs[retrive_ind]])
              #print("X",X)

              self.synaptic_weights+= adjustment_delta * X * self.l_r

    def think(self, inputs):
        weighted=np.dot(self.synaptic_weights, inputs.T)
        return (weighted, self.__sigmoid(weighted))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    neural_network = NeuralNetwork()

    print("Random starting synaptic weights: ")
    print(neural_network.synaptic_weights)

    training_set_inputs = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                                 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                 [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                                 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

    training_set_outputs = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]).T

    neural_network.train(training_set_inputs, training_set_outputs, 10)

    print("New synaptic weights after training: ")
    print(neural_network.synaptic_weights)
```

[cmd]

```
Random starting synaptic weights: 
[[-0.25091976  0.90142861  0.46398788  0.19731697 -0.68796272 -0.68801096
  -0.88383278]]
error [[-0.03246489]]
error [[-0.0745709]]
error [[-0.12905986]]
error [[-0.1239805]]
error [[0.12919432]]
error [[0.07983066]]
error [[0.07957007]]
error [[0.07747834]]
error [[-0.03240493]]
error [[-0.0743714]]
error [[-0.12865101]]
error [[-0.12440705]]
error [[0.12895055]]
error [[0.07961511]]
error [[0.07935421]]
error [[0.07745035]]
error [[-0.03234761]]
error [[-0.07417432]]
error [[-0.12823997]]
error [[-0.12483372]]
error [[0.12870773]]
error [[0.07940459]]
error [[0.07914337]]
error [[0.07743354]]
error [[-0.03229295]]
error [[-0.07397967]]
error [[-0.12782673]]
error [[-0.12526049]]
error [[0.12846597]]
error [[0.07919917]]
error [[0.07893766]]
error [[0.07742813]]
error [[-0.03224092]]
error [[-0.07378744]]
error [[-0.1274113]]
error [[-0.12568735]]
error [[0.1282254]]
error [[0.07899894]]
error [[0.07873715]]
error [[0.07743434]]
New synaptic weights after training: 
[[-0.28496149  0.93657717  0.46922246  0.21811004 -0.68086341 -0.70116573
  -0.88383278]]
```